# What is the difference between tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder and tf.contrib.seq2seq.BeamSearchDecoder mechanism?

Tags: tensorflow, decoder, beam-search

I am building a seq2seq model with tensorflow.
Can you explain the details of the two beam search functions?
Thank you.

tf.nn.ctc.beam_search_decoder
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_beam_search_decoder

tf.contrib.seq2seq.BeamSearchDecoder
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/BeamSearchDecoder